# Execute Code after firestore get method is finished

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I know that using java (android) you can execute code after the get method is finished, is that also possible when using javascript?

Here is my code:

```
      mColRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot){
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
              console.log(doc.id);
          });
      });
```

Can I do something like this? Or how would you code something like this for web (javascript)?

```
     mColRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot){
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
              console.log(doc.id);
          });
      }).OnCompleteListener(new OncompleteListener ....
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're overcomplicating things.  The use of `then()` on a promise in JavaScript serves the same purpose as the use of an `OnCompleteListener` on a `Task` object in Android.  Just put the code you want to execute after `get()` completes inside the function you're already passing to `then()` in your code sample.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks for your help! (I am kind of new to javascript)